# New Value not added to list (C#)

Tags: c#, list

I am trying to create a list of clients. When a user inserts a name of a new client, this name must be added to the list and be shown in a Messagebox. The pre-configured clients are Jack, Sandra, Anna, Tom and Bob. When I run the following script and enter a new client name, a pop-up comes up without the new name. Why is this?

```
    private void btnAddClient_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string msg = "";

        List<string> Clients = new List<string>();
        Clients.Add("Jack");
        Clients.Add("Sandra");
        Clients.Add("Anna");
        Clients.Add("Tom");
        Clients.Add("Bob");

        foreach (string val in Clients)
        {
            msg += "- " + val + "\n";
        }

        if (txtAddClient.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No client name has been entered!");
        }
        else
        {
            string newClient = txtAddClient.Text;
            Clients.Add(newClient);
            MessageBox.Show(msg);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATED:

```
private List<string> Clients = new List<string>(){ "Jack", "Sandra", "Anna", "Tom", "Bob"};

private void btnAddClient_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string msg = "";

    if (txtAddClient.Text == "")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("No client name has been entered!");
    }
    else
    {
        string newClient = txtAddClient.Text;
        Clients.Add(newClient);
        foreach (string val in Clients)
        {
            msg += "- " + val + "\n";
        }
        MessageBox.Show(msg);
    }
}
```

Comment: If I do it this way, I can only use it one time instead of multiple times. I wouldn't be able to add a second name.

Comment: @AnnoyingBot You're not making sense. Explain this more

Comment: @Jon I need to be able to use the button more often, so each time I press the button a new name must be added to the client list. With the example that Tisho game me, only the text in the textbox is being added, when I change the text in the textbox and press the button again, the name simply changes and doesn't get added to the earlier inserted name. There will always be 6 names, and I can't possibly get 7 names in the list, because it doesn't get added.

Comment: So you want to modify existing items in the list? If so that's another question. We have all answered your initial question

Comment: No, I want to add items to the list. With the code Tisho gave me I can only add one item, but when I try to add another one the initial one I added gets changed.

Answer (score 3):

Because you have not appended the msg variable with the data in the textbox.

You loop over the existing clients and append the variable but once you have decided that the textbox is not empty, you add contents to the list and display the msg variable. You need to append the msg variable with the entered data.

See @Tisho's code example how to implement it - didn't want to copy his code as my own

Answer (score 1):

```
    private void btnAddClient_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string msg = "";

        List<string> Clients = new List<string>();
        Clients.Add("Jack");
        Clients.Add("Sandra");
        Clients.Add("Anna");
        Clients.Add("Tom");
        Clients.Add("Bob");

        if (txtAddClient.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No client name has been entered!");
        }
        else
        {
            string newClient = txtAddClient.Text;
            Clients.Add(newClient);

            // this is where you want to join your string
            // AFTER you add the new client to the list
            foreach (string val in Clients)
            {
                msg += "- " + val + "\n";
            }

            MessageBox.Show(msg);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you must do

```
msg += txtAddClient.Text;
```

and then

```
MessageBox.Show(msg);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    List<string> Clients = new List<string>();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Clients.Add("Jack");
        Clients.Add("Sandra");
        Clients.Add("Anna");
        Clients.Add("Tom");
        Clients.Add("Bob");
    }

    private void btnAddClient_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtAddClient.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No client name has been entered!");
        }
        else
        {
            string msg = "";
            string newClient = txtAddClient.Text;
            Clients.Add(newClient);
            foreach (string val in Clients)
            {
                msg += "- " + val + "\n";
            }
            MessageBox.Show(msg);
        }
    }
}
```